# Creating a html page that store data dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a HTML page, which when entered any text in text area, that text should be populated into the page and when closed the page and opened again, the previously entered data should be seen there.  Please help me achieve this...

I dont want this with the help of PHP.

Please refer the below image for what i was trying
[My page what i was trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyDZ7.png)

Comment: You can use localStorage for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can save data on the client by using [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (or use a fallback with cookies), an example implementation could look like:

```js
// tiny utils to save and load entered text
const saveText = (text) => localStorage.setItem('text', JSON.stringify(text))
const loadText = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('text'))

// get a reference to our `textarea` and listen for changes
document
  .querySelector('textarea')
  .addEventListener('change', evt => saveText(evt.target.value))


// somewhere else in the app, e.g. on load, you could prefill the textarea
document.querySelector('textarea').value = loadText()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help
 Can you give me the whole html code for that. I am a beginner in this area. So the whole code will help me alot
Thanks in advance

Comment: The more useful example of what I want will be a chat application
If you see any chat application, it will save all the historical data and we can view it at anytime
I need that without the help of PHP or any server